# @Async methods return empty lists. Why?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to play around with `@Async`. My first experience with it isn't very positive. I get an empty list where results are definitely expected

MRE:

```java
public interface AsynchronousCardRepository extends Repository<Card, UUID> {
    @Async
    Future<List<Card>> findAll();
}
```

```java
@DataJpaTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@Sql(
        executionPhase = Sql.ExecutionPhase.BEFORE_TEST_METHOD,
        scripts = {"/schema-h2.sql", "/data-h2.sql"}
)
public class AsynchronousCardRepositoryTest {
    @Autowired
    AsynchronousCardRepository cardRepository;

    @Test
    @SneakyThrows
    void findAll() {
        Future<List<Card>> futureCards = cardRepository.findAll();
        List<Card> cards = futureCards.get();
        assertThat(cards).asList().hasSize(3);
    }
}
```

```sql
-- schema

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PUBLIC.account
(
    id                        UUID           PRIMARY KEY
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PUBLIC.card
(
    id                UUID             PRIMARY KEY,
    account_id        UUID             NOT NULL REFERENCES account (id),
    status            VARCHAR(30)      NOT NULL
);
```

```sql
-- data

INSERT INTO PUBLIC.ACCOUNT
VALUES ('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000ac1');

INSERT INTO PUBLIC.CARD
VALUES ('00000000-0000-0000-0000-0000000000c1', '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000ac1', 'ACTIVE');

INSERT INTO PUBLIC.CARD
VALUES ('00000000-0000-0000-0000-0000000000c2', '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000ac1', 'ACTIVE');

INSERT INTO PUBLIC.CARD
VALUES ('00000000-0000-0000-0000-0000000000c3', '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000ac1', 'NON_ACTIVE');
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "card")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class Card {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private UUID id;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "account_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Account account;
    @Enumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)
    private CardStatus status;
}
```

```java
public enum CardStatus {
    ACTIVE, NON_ACTIVE
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "account")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class Account {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private UUID id;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "account")
    private List<Card> cards;
}
```

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAsync // funny enough, if you remove it, everything works
public class CreditServiceApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CreditServiceApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

```yaml
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;MODE=MySQL;DATABASE_TO_LOWER=TRUE
    driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
    username: sa
    password:
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
    show-sql: true
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
    properties:
      hibernate:
        format_sql: true
  h2:
    console:
      enabled: false
      settings:
        web-allow-others: true
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: test

logging:
  level:
    org:
      hibernate:
        type: TRACE
      springframework:
          jdbc:
            core: TRACE
            datasource:
              init: DEBUG
          test:
            context:
              jdbc: DEBUG
```

The method doesn't return anything:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected size: 3 but was: 0 in:
[]

    at by.afinny.credit.unit.repository.AsynchronousCardRepositoryTest.findAll(AsynchronousCardRepositoryTest.java:32)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
```

Why is it happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause of the test failure is due to a combination of:

1. The `@DataJpaTest` annotation itself is annotated with `@Transactional`, this mean the test will run inside a transaction, also indicated by the Javadoc in `DataJpaTest`:

   > By default, tests annotated with `@DataJpaTest` are transactional and roll back at the end of each test.
2. Your test is using `@Sql(executionPhase = Sql.ExecutionPhase.BEFORE_TEST_METHOD, ...)`, so the SQL scripts will run within the test's transaction, therefore any data created by the script is uncommitted data while the test is running.
3. Your async `findAll()` will run in a different thread, outside of the test's transaction, and due to [transaction isolation](https://h2database.com/html/advanced.html#transaction_isolation) (default is read committed), it will not see uncommitted data created in the test, hence it will return nothing.

Any one of the following can workaround this (mostly copied from the answer by @g00glen00b) and why they work:

- Use `@SpringBootTest` instead of `@DataJpaTest` - this works because `@SpringBootTest` itself is not annotated with `@Transactional`, so there is no outer transaction wrapping the test, everything is committed as soon as their calls finish, so `findAll()` will see the committed test data.
- Use `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NEVER)` or `Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED` on the test, this essentially suspends the test transaction coming from `@DataJpaTest`, so will cause the test to run without a wrapping transaction, having similar affect as the above.
- Use `@Sql(executionPhase = Sql.ExecutionPhase.BEFORE_TEST_CLASS, ...)` - this runs and commits the test data before the test starts, therefore not affected by the test's own transaction.
- Remove `@Async` on `findAll()` - this will cause `findAll()` to run within the same transaction, therefore will see uncommitted data.

Answer (score 3):

While I don't know the exact cause, it seems to be related to how transactions are handled in `@DataJpaTest`. If you run the application regularly, the `findAll()` method works fine.

Similarly, if you use `@SpringBootTest` in stead of `@DataJpaTest`, your test also works:

```java
@SpringBootTest // Replace @DataJpaTest with @SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@Sql(
    executionPhase = Sql.ExecutionPhase.BEFORE_TEST_METHOD,
    scripts = {"/schema-h2.sql", "/data-h2.sql"}
)
public class AsynchronousCardRepositoryTest {
    // ...
}
```

The reason why I suspect that this is transaction related is because if I change the execution phase of the SQL to be `BEFORE_TEST_CLASS`, your test succeeds:

```java
@DataJpaTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
// Replace BEFORE_TEST_METHOD with BEFORE_TEST_CLASS
@Sql(
    executionPhase = Sql.ExecutionPhase.BEFORE_TEST_CLASS,
    scripts = {"/schema-h2.sql", "/data-h2.sql"}
)
public class AsynchronousCardRepositoryTest {
    // ...
}
```

Alternatively, if I annotate your test with `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NEVER)`, your test also succeeds:

```java
@DataJpaTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@Sql(
    executionPhase = Sql.ExecutionPhase.BEFORE_TEST_METHOD,
    scripts = {"/schema-h2.sql", "/data-h2.sql"}
)
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NEVER) // Add this
public class AsynchronousCardRepositoryTest {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you think there is some asynchronous alternative for `@DataJpaTest`? I'm sure there's some "official" way of doing it

Comment: @Kodigas I don't think there is. But I also like to know why this happens and since your MRE is pretty detailed, I'm going to add a bounty later today to ask for a more authoritative answer if I don't forget.

Comment: A gentle reminder if you still want to do that

Answer (score -1):

When you use @Async on a method, Spring creates a proxy around that method to handle the asynchronous behavior. However, if the method is called from within the same class, the proxy won't be invoked, and the asynchronous behavior may not take effect.

There are couple of thing that can be tried to get rid of the issue -

1. Move the findAll() call to another class:
   Create a separate service or component class, inject the AsynchronousCardRepository into that class, and call the findAll() method from there. This ensures that the proxy is invoked, and the asynchronous behavior is properly handled.

   ```
   @Service
   public class CardService {

   private final AsynchronousCardRepository cardRepository;

   @Autowired
   public CardService(AsynchronousCardRepository cardRepository) {
      this.cardRepository = cardRepository;
   }

    @Async
    public CompletableFuture<List<Card>> findAll() {
       return cardRepository.findAll();
    }
   }
   ```

In Test Class
@Autowired
private CardService cardService;

```
 @Test
 @SneakyThrows
 void findAll() {
    CompletableFuture<List<Card>> futureCards = cardService.findAll();
    List<Card> cards = futureCards.get();
    assertThat(cards).asList().hasSize(3);
  }
```

2. Use CompletableFuture instead of Future:
   You can modify the return type of the findAll() method to use CompletableFuture directly. This might work more seamlessly with Spring's asynchronous processing.

Let me know if this resolves your problem.

Comment: Let me clarify please. Do you mean the actual method implementation in the proxy Spring Data creates is not marked with `@Async` and is not wrapped in an asynchronous proxy?

Comment: The method itself is not invoked from the same class so this answer is irrelevant.